# error message not appearing, validate array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Please help me showing my error message, array message not appears in table

```
$validation_file = $this->validate([
            'requirements' => 'required|array',
            'requirements.*' => 'required|array',
            'requirements.*.file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,jpeg|max:20000|array',
            'input.*.input' => 'required|array',
            'requirements.*.file.input' => 'required|array',
            
        ]);
```

Blade

```
<input type="hidden" name="req_id[{{ $key }}]" wire:model="req_id.{{ $key }}.id" value="{{ $requirements->id }}">
<input type='file' wire:model="requirement.{{ $requirements->id }}.file" class="form-control" accept=".pdf">
@error('requirements.{{ $key }}.file')
<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror

<input type="hidden" name="req_id[{{ $key }}]" wire:model="req_id.{{ $key }}.id" value="{{ $input->id }}">
<input type='text' wire:model.defer="input.{{ $input->id }}.input" class="form-control">
@error('input.{{ $key }}.input')
<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: Your front has related div with codes to show errors?

Comment: Is that your entire blade ile?

Answer (score 0):

Your `wire:model` has a spelling error:

`wire:model="requirement.{{ $requirements->id }}.file"`

It should be (notice the missing **s**):

`wire:model="requirements.{{ $requirements->id }}.file"`

Comment: Sorry Bro Not Working

Comment: @Bilhaq2612 So, you've changed the `wire:model`, then uploaded a file, and inside your component triggered [validation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation)?